# Unity object resize based on screen height did wrong

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

( if you have better script with same function , i accept all no matter c# or javascript )

[ my preference resolution is 1366 x 768]

i don't know what to do now , with this c# ( c sharp ) script i can calculate any object using any resolution width size  , but when i change the resolution height size ( from 768 ) , the object resizing in wrong way , this is my c# ( c sharp ) script : ( sorry i use snippet due to error when posting code ! )

```js
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class guicontrol : MonoBehaviour {
 void CalculateResolution(string ObjectName) {
  GameObject theobject = GameObject.Find (ObjectName);
  float selectedwidth = 1366;
  float selectedheight = 768;
  float objectscaley = theobject.transform.localScale.y;
  float objectscalex = theobject.transform.localScale.x;
  Debug.Log ("current object [ x : " + objectscalex + " | y : " + objectscaley + " ] ");
  float screenwidth = Screen.width;
  float screenheight = Screen.height;
  float coordinatey = theobject.transform.localPosition.y;
  float coordinatex = theobject.transform.localPosition.x;
  Debug.Log ("work at current stats : " + screenwidth + " " + screenheight);
  if (screenwidth != selectedwidth || screenheight != selectedheight) {
   float halfthree = 1 / 3;
   float coordinateytomove = (screenheight / selectedheight) * coordinatey;
   float coordinatextomove = (screenwidth / selectedwidth) * coordinatex;
   theobject.transform.position = new Vector2 (coordinatextomove, coordinateytomove);
   Debug.Log (coordinateytomove + " " + coordinatextomove);
   float scaleytochange = (screenheight / selectedheight) * objectscaley;
   float scalextochange = (screenwidth / selectedwidth) * objectscalex;
   theobject.transform.localScale = new Vector2 (scalextochange, scaleytochange);
   Debug.Log (scaleytochange + " " + scalextochange);

  }

 }
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
  Debug.Log ("current position of startbox : " + transform.localPosition);
  Debug.Log ("current screen resolution : " + Screen.currentResolution);
  Debug.Log ("current screen width : " + Screen.width);
  Debug.Log ("current screen height : " + Screen.height);
  CalculateResolution ("startbox");
  CalculateResolution ("background");
 }
 
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
 
 }
}
```

if there's any previous post that answer this tell me ! or give me better script ( javascript or c sharp all i accept ) but still with same function please :) .

Screenshot :
( 1024 x 768 )
[image: 1024 x 768]
( 300 x 768 )
[image: 300 x 768 EASTER EGG !]
( 1024 x 600 ) ( wrong ) 
[image: 1024 x 600]

you can see the different at screenshot , any help would be appreciated ! :) .

EDITED !
EDITED ! 01/10/2016
when i use canvas and removed my script from any object , the canvas just do worst thing , it's work normal for preference resolution ( 1366 x 768 ) , but when i change the resolution , it's do wrong in resolution 1024 x 768 ( which previously work ) ( look up for screenshot that 1024 x 768 work with script )

Screenshot : 
[image: 1024x768 Canvas]

Answer (score 0):

This whole thing is unnecessary. Starting from Unity 4.6, if you want to make a button, use the `Button` component. Use the new Unity UI. If you want to display a UI image, use the Image or RawImage component.

The only time you should use `SpriteRenderer` is when the image is a character or part of the environment that colliders with the character and also needs to use a Rigidbody. If the image is simply there as a UI or background and does not collide with anything, you need to use the UI to do this instead of `SpriteRenderer`.

When UI is used, you can easily do auto resize with `Canvas Scaler`, anchors and pivot point without writing a single line of code. Canvas Scaler will automatically resize your Image to any screen size.

To create a simple Button in Unity, go to **GameObject**->**UI**->**Button**.
Here is a tutorial for [Unity UI](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui).

You can also see [UI TOOLS: RESOLUTION & DEVICE INDEPENDENCE](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-tools-resolution-device-independence). It shows ways to make UI automatically resize for any device.

Comment: thanks for telling me about canvas :) but still not work

Comment: You are doing something wrong. Is this game for mobile(iOS,Android) or desktop?